# Name a constant with respect to the current theorem-like environment

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have a lot of lemmas. In each lemma, I have a constant.
Is it a possible way to name the constant with respect to the name of the lemma? (automatic way)

Example:
"Lemma 1.1: there is a constant `c_{1.1}` depending on ..."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to provide more information about how you define theorem-like environments. E.g., do you employ the `amsthm` or `ntheorem` package do create theorem-like environments?

Comment: `c_{\ref{lem}}` should work fine, but it might not be a good naming convention as it will probably confuse most users

Comment: Thank you. @daleif do you have any suggestions on how should I name them?

Comment: Not really I don't know your use case. I would probably use a textual name like then one does `R_{\textup{lake}}` for the radius of a lake, and then give each a proper textual name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

1. If the constants associated with various lemmas (or is that "lemmata"?) are only ever used inside their own lemma-like environments, it suffices to write `$c_{\thelemma}`.
2. If the constants may need to be cross-referenced *outside* their native lemma-like environments, you should write `\begin{lemma} \label{lem:a} ... $c_{\ref{lem:a}}$ ... \end{lemma}`, etc.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsthm} % or '\usepackage{ntheorem}'
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

% Approach 1
\stepcounter{section}
\begin{lemma} 
If the constant $c_{\thelemma}$ satisfies \dots 
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma} 
If some other constant $c_{\thelemma}$ satisfies \dots 
\end{lemma}

\bigskip
% Approach 2
\stepcounter{section} 
\begin{lemma} \label{lem:a} 
Suppose the constant $c_{\ref{lem:a}}$ satisfies \dots 
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma} \label{lem:b} 
Suppose the constants $c_{\ref{lem:a}}$ and $c_{\ref{lem:b}}$ satisfy \dots 
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```